# Button calling javascript function error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my view, I want two buttons to populate three hidden fields of a form and submit it. It's not working, and I can't know why. Any ideas?

I have the following code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function FillAndSubmit(thisid) {
        $('input[name=First]').val(thisid);
        $('input[name=Second]').val(@Model.ID);
        $('input[name=Third]').val(@ViewBag.Something);
        document.form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

A have a form with invisible fields:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, 
                       new { name = "form", id = "form" }))
{
    @Html.Hidden("First")
    @Html.Hidden("Second")
    @Html.Hidden("Third")
}
```

And two buttons:

```
<button class="Button" id="ButtonA" onclick="javascript:FillAndSubmit(this.id);">
    CaptionA
</button>
<button class="Button" id="ButtonB" onclick="javascript:FillAndSubmit(this.id);">
    CaptionB
</button>
```

If I put the buttons inside the scope of the form, it submits but without populating the hidden fields. So, it is just not calling the function. Javascript is working in other pages of the same application.

**ADDED:**

Generated source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function Botao(thisid) {
            $('input[name=First]').val(thisid);
            $('input[name=Second]').val(41); 
            $('input[name=Third]').val(10/5/2012 1:58:02 PM);
            document.form.submit();
        }
</script>

...
Some div's with some text
...


<form action="/Controller/Action/" id="form" method="post" name="form"><input id="First" name="First" type="hidden" value="" /><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The DateTime field is required." id="Second" name="Second" type="hidden" value="10/5/2012 1:58:02 PM" /><input id="Third" name="Third" type="hidden" value="" /></form>        
    <button class="Button" id="ButtonA" onclick="javascript:Botao(this.id);">
        CaptionA
    </button>

    <button class="myButton" id="ButtonB" onclick="javascript:Botao(this.id);">
        CaptionB
    </button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us the generated source.

Comment: Does the browser's JS console show any error?. Have you tried to remove the `javascript:` part of your `onclick` attributes since is not needed?. Have you tried to debug with a `console.log` to see if the function is called?. Have you tried to call the function directly from the Browser's JS console?

Comment: Removing the `javascript:` didn't do anything. I will check the JS console now.

Comment: Unless @mokdel.ID is a number you will get an unknow identifier at val(@Model.ID) same for the line below

Comment: `Model.ID` is a number, and `ViewBag.Something` is a `DateTime`.

Comment: How do I call the function from the browser? I have here IE9, Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery's `.val(value)` accepts either string or array of strings, place quotes around `@Model.ID` and `@ViewBag.Something`:

```
    $('input[name=Second]').val("@Model.ID");
    $('input[name=Third]').val("@ViewBag.Something");
```

Comment: It worked, and I just typed `"@Model.ID"` and `"@ViewBag.Something"`!

Answer (score 3):

This needs quotes:

`$('input[name=momentoDaConsulta]').val("10/5/2012 1:58:02 PM");`

Comment: But this date is generated by Razor engine. The code has a `.val(@ViewBag.Something)`.

Comment: I don't care what generates it, the generated code is wrong. It tries to divide, then fails on those other numbers ("SyntaxError: Unexpected number") and the last command never gets called - which is, by coincidence, the "document.form.submit();"

Comment: It worked! I put double quote in `"@Model.ID"` and `"@ViewBag.Something"`!